# Dismiss or pop alert dialog on press of a fire stick remote button

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm building an app for fire tv/fire stick using flutter.

My requirement: Show a dialog on press of a button in the fire TV remote and hide the dialog when the user presses the back button on the remote.

What I have accomplished: I'm able to show the dialog on the press of a button on the remote.

I need help in dismissing the dialog when the user presses back button on the remote.

What is happening now: When I press back while the dialog is shown, the entire page gets rerouted to the previous page.

I'm guessing it has something to do with the context, not sure how to fix this issue.

```
_showInfoModal(context) {
    return showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          content: Container(
              child: Center(
                child: Text(widget.message, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
              ),
            )
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

This is the code I'm using to show the dialog.

```
Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
```

This is how I'm trying to pop the alert dialog.

Can someone please help me out here? TIA.

Comment: use Navigator.of(context).pop(true);

Comment: Hi Ravindra, this doesn't seem to work either. This would usually work if I have a button in the UI and show the dialog on button press. But doesn't work in my scenario.

Comment: you build APP for TV?

Comment: Yes, I'm building app for TV

Comment: refer my below answer

Answer (score 1):

So I was able to accomplish this using a workaround.
Having a boolean variable and showing either the dialog or a container with 0 height.

Not a good approach but gets the work done.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code hope its works because I also build apk for TV  and use below Alert Code

```
showAlert(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Top '),
          content: Text('Bottom '),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
              child: Text('Ok'),
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

Comment: I'm not able to select the TextButton to click in this. I even tried Modal Bottom Sheet, same issue in that too. When I try to navigate to the button, changes reflect in the main page and not in the alert dialog.